# Get value from node in XML - position

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML document which i want to parse in SQL. Below you can find part of document

[MyXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3xLt.jpg)

I am using a standard query but i don't know how to extract value @ID underlined in attached picture. Query below:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLData

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT 

[RID]

FROM 

OPENXML(@hDoc, 'OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif/HotelReservations/HotelReservation')

WITH 
(
[RID]                           varchar(5)      '../../POS/Source/RequestorID/@ID[2]'
) --this part need an update

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Would really appreciate help with this one.

Regards

Comment: Post the XML, not a screenshot of a tool displaying it graphically.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I can't post XML as it has sensitive data.

Comment: ...huh? Then remove/redact the sensitive data.

Comment: You can obfuscate your XML.

Answer (score -1):

I made it somehow. Maybe someone will use it:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLData

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT 

[RID]

FROM 

OPENXML(@hDoc, 'OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif/HotelReservations/HotelReservation')

WITH 
(
[RID]                           varchar(5)      
'../../POS/Source[2]/RequestorID/@ID'
) --[2] should be here with SOURCE node as it has 2 rows - not with @ID. 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Comment: ...and now tell me how anybody could have guessed the correct XPath just by looking at your screenshot. There is not enough information in the screenshot for that. Let alone that nobody could copy working XML from your question to actually test their answer before posting it.

Comment: Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use XQuery language, based on the w3c standards, while dealing with the XML data type.
Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL 
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
It is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.